# Question about number of occurences of a function symbol in a Term Rewriting System

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics, rewriting-systems

While studying Termination of term rewriting systems I came across the folowing problem from Baader's book Term Rewriting and All That

[image]

$\textbf{My idea:}$

Let $s\rightarrow_R t$, then there exists $p\in Pos(s)$, $l=r \in R$ and a substitution $\sigma$ such that
$$s|_p=\sigma(l)$$
$$t=s[\sigma(r)]_p$$
From $s|_p=\sigma(l)$ we have that $|s|_p|_f=|\sigma(l)|_f$.

From $t=s[\sigma(r)]_p$ we have that $|t|_f=|s|_f-|s|_p|_f+|\sigma(r)|_f$.

Thus, $|t|_f=|s|_f+(|\sigma(r)|_f-|\sigma(l)|_f)$. But I can't conclude that $|\sigma(r)|_f-|\sigma(l)|_f\geq0$.

I'm not sure if this is the right aproach for this problem, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, your approach lacks the consideration of how TRS $R$ is like.
The key of this proposition seems that a constant $k$ depends on TRS $R$ and function symbol $f$, and doesn’t depend on terms $s$ and $t$.

If I approach this problem, I would try to determine $k$ for given TRS $R$ and $f$. A constant $k$ probably depends on the maximum number of occurrence of $f$ on lhs minus occurrence of $f$ on rhs of rules (I haven’t tried yet, so this might be wrong).